# How to transfer Selenium from one PC to another PC?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests

I'm facing problem using Selenium IDE for Firefox for testing. I have created tests suits and running it fine on my PC. The moment I transfer it to my fellow developer working on another PC, all tests created by me starts to fail. The same thing happens when I run test cases created by him on my browser.

What could be causing issue? And how to transfer selenium test case from one system to another? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was running Selenium IDE tests a lots of times - and most of them were created by someone else. I also had the problem of tests failing and mostly it was caused by speed of Selenium.

Try to move the speed of execution to "slow" - it can help.

If not - is there specific place when the tests do fail?